# Text and Image allignment

Tags: html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <title>Reliant Industrial Supply</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://http://www.reliantindustrialsupply.com/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,600">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.jpg"
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>

    <style amp-custom>

:root {
--background: rgba(299, 299, 299, .95);
}

*, *::before, *::after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* navigation styles start here */

header {
background: var(--background);
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
width: 100%;
}


.nav-toggle {
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
}

.nav-toggle:focus ~ .nav-toggle-label {
outline: 3px solid rgba(lightblue, .75);
}

.nav-toggle-label {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-left: 1em;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.nav-toggle-label span,
.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
display: block;
background: black;
height: 2px;
width: 2em;
border-radius: 2px;
position: relative;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before {
bottom: 7px;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::after {
top: 7px;
}

nav {
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
background: var(--background);
width: 100%;
transform: scale(1, 0);
transform-origin: top;
transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
}

nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

nav li {
margin-bottom: 1em;
margin-left: 1em;
}

nav a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.2rem;
text-transform: uppercase;
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}

nav a:hover {
color: #000;
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav {
transform: scale(1,1);
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav a {
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

amp-carousel {
  padding-top: 20em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
.nav-toggle-label {
  display: none;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(600px, 3fr) 1fr;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

nav {


  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  transition: none;
  transform: scale(1,1);
  background: none;
  top: initial;
  left: initial;

  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  margin-left: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav a {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -.75em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: scale(0, 1);
  transition: transform ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1,1);
}
}

amp-carousel {
  padding-top: 60em;
}

.content {
  background-color: dark-grey;
}
.Centered{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Work Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.left {
  padding-right: 50%;
  margin: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Work Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

img {
  margin-left: 50%
}




    </style>

<script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.2.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-video" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-video-0.1.js"></script>

  </head>
  <header>
    <h1>logo</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/pilot/Documents/GitHub/AMP/Home/Home-Page.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/pilot/Documents/GitHub/AMP/Contact/Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </header>

  <body>


<amp-carousel layout="fixed-height"
  type="slides"
  height="500"
  controls
  loop
  autoplay
  delay="3000"  data-next-button-aria-label="Go to next slide"
  data-previous-button-aria-label="Go to previous slide">
  <amp-img src="http://www.reliantindustrialsupply.com/images/banner1.jpg"
  width="100%"
  height="100%"></amp-img>
  <amp-img src="https://i.imgur.com/xxlkv2g.jpg"
  width="100%"
  height="100%"></amp-img>
  <amp-img src="https://i.imgur.com/mKQncTG.jpg"
  width="100%"
  height="100%"></amp-img>
  <amp-img src="https://i.imgur.com/F4jWDpd.jpg"
  width="100%"
  height="100%"></amp-img>
  <amp-img src="https://i.imgur.com/wWyxGeL.jpg"
  width="100%"
  height="100%"></amp-img>
  <amp-video
  layout="fixed"
  autoplay
  loop
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  poster="https://i.imgur.com/lNFDJb1.png">
  <source src="https://i.imgur.com/3TFahoU.mp4"
    type="video/mp4" />
  <div fallback>
    <p>This browser does not support this video element.</p>
  </div>
  </amp-video>
  </amp-carousel>

  <div class='content'>
    <h1 class="Centered">Providing solutions for all your surface treatments</h1>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <p class="left">Reliant Industrial Supply provides solutions for all your surface treatments.Our supplier sia Coated Abrasives, the oldest abrasive manufacturer in the world, brings one of the best abrasives on the market. We supply Flex Trim brushes for all liner and carousel sanding needs. We provide AirVantage Sanders and Coilhose Pneumatics, for when you want the best quality handsanding tools and results. When it comes to machines, we have one of the best and also one of the most experienced machinery manufacturers, Timesavers Wide Belt Sanders. For cutting and shaping we have a wide variety of Exchangeable Saw Blades and Router Bits. Whether cutting, shaping or sanding, you can rely on Reliant. We provide solutions for surface preparation through complete sanding systems which include coated abrasives, pneumatic sanders and machinery.</p>

      <img class="right"src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/9b21f5a4-2e5f-41f0-8dad-efd23bed0d9a/d4afbws-c0d0181e-3af5-4396-8a25-03179fe90de4.png/v1/fill/w_800,h_200,q_80,strp/blitzle_banner_800x200_by_poketrainertk_d4afbws-fullview.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOiIsImlzcyI6InVybjphcHA6Iiwib2JqIjpbW3siaGVpZ2h0IjoiPD0yMDAiLCJwYXRoIjoiXC9mXC85YjIxZjVhNC0yZTVmLTQxZjAtOGRhZC1lZmQyM2JlZDBkOWFcL2Q0YWZid3MtYzBkMDE4MWUtM2FmNS00Mzk2LThhMjUtMDMxNzlmZTkwZGU0LnBuZyIsIndpZHRoIjoiPD04MDAifV1dLCJhdWQiOlsidXJuOnNlcnZpY2U6aW1hZ2Uub3BlcmF0aW9ucyJdfQ.i-LS_KPDS28_jEfNNLQ7CuIXHSH38heUTJKHQU_ZYZc"
        layout="responsive"
        width = 800px;
        height = 200px;>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried many solutions listed on stack overflow, such as display:inline, but they do not work. I have used things such as a responsive layout. Also I am trying to make the AMP compatible so that also might be an issue. I don't know exactly if the syntax of AMP might interfere with position of images and text Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank you for posting your code. Last important things, what is the problem that you are having and what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: The problem that I am having is the that the text and the image at the bottom are not inline, and I do not know how to align them. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the p and img in divs and assign container with the .clearfix class a display of flex. This aligns the bottom paragraph and text right next to eachother.

You would just need to play around with the behavior of the divs for responsiveness.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <title>Reliant Industrial Supply</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link
      rel="canonical"
      href="https://http://www.reliantindustrialsupply.com/"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,600"
    />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1"
    />
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": ["logo.jpg"]
      }
    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>
      body {
        -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
        animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
      @keyframes -amp-start {
        from {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        to {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <noscript
      ><style amp-boilerplate>
        body {
          -webkit-animation: none;
          -moz-animation: none;
          -ms-animation: none;
          animation: none;
        }
      </style></noscript
    >

    <style amp-custom>
      :root {
        --background: rgba(299, 299, 299, 0.95);
      }

      *,
      *::before,
      *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      /* navigation styles start here */

      header {
        background: var(--background);
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .nav-toggle {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
      }

      .nav-toggle:focus ~ .nav-toggle-label {
        outline: 3px solid rgba(lightblue, 0.75);
      }

      .nav-toggle-label {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 1em;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .nav-toggle-label span,
      .nav-toggle-label span::before,
      .nav-toggle-label span::after {
        display: block;
        background: black;
        height: 2px;
        width: 2em;
        border-radius: 2px;
        position: relative;
      }

      .nav-toggle-label span::before,
      .nav-toggle-label span::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
      }

      .nav-toggle-label span::before {
        bottom: 7px;
      }

      .nav-toggle-label span::after {
        top: 7px;
      }

      nav {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        background: var(--background);
        width: 100%;
        transform: scale(1, 0);
        transform-origin: top;
        transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
      }

      nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
      }

      nav li {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        margin-left: 1em;
      }

      nav a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
      }

      nav a:hover {
        color: #000;
      }

      .nav-toggle:checked ~ nav {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
      }

      .nav-toggle:checked ~ nav a {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
      }

      amp-carousel {
        padding-top: 20em;
      }

      @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
        .nav-toggle-label {
          display: none;
        }

        header {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(600px, 3fr) 1fr;
        }

        .logo {
          grid-column: 2 / 3;
        }

        nav {
          position: relative;
          text-align: left;
          transition: none;
          transform: scale(1, 1);
          background: none;
          top: initial;
          left: initial;

          grid-column: 3 / 4;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: flex-end;
          align-items: center;
        }

        nav ul {
          display: flex;
        }

        nav li {
          margin-left: 3em;
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        nav a {
          opacity: 1;
          position: relative;
        }

        nav a::before {
          content: "";
          display: block;
          height: 5px;
          background: black;
          position: absolute;
          top: -0.75em;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          transform: scale(0, 1);
          transition: transform ease-in-out 250ms;
        }

        nav a:hover::before {
          transform: scale(1, 1);
        }
      }

      amp-carousel {
        padding-top: 60em;
      }

      .content {
        background-color: dark-grey;
      }
      .Centered {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Work Sans";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      .left {
        margin: 2rem;
        font-family: "Work Sans";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      .clearfix {
        overflow: auto;
        display: flex;
      }
    </style>

    <script
      async
      custom-element="amp-carousel"
      src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.2.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      async
      custom-element="amp-video"
      src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-video-0.1.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <header>
    <h1>logo</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle" />
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a
            href="file:///C:/Users/pilot/Documents/GitHub/AMP/Home/Home-Page.html"
            >Home</a
          >
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li>
          <a
            href="file:///C:/Users/pilot/Documents/GitHub/AMP/Contact/Contact.html"
            >Contact</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </header>

  <body>
    <amp-carousel
      layout="fixed-height"
      type="slides"
      height="500"
      controls
      loop
      autoplay
      delay="3000"
      data-next-button-aria-label="Go to next slide"
      data-previous-button-aria-label="Go to previous slide"
    >
      <amp-img
        src="http://www.reliantindustrialsupply.com/images/banner1.jpg"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      ></amp-img>
      <amp-img
        src="https://i.imgur.com/xxlkv2g.jpg"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      ></amp-img>
      <amp-img
        src="https://i.imgur.com/mKQncTG.jpg"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      ></amp-img>
      <amp-img
        src="https://i.imgur.com/F4jWDpd.jpg"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      ></amp-img>
      <amp-img
        src="https://i.imgur.com/wWyxGeL.jpg"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      ></amp-img>
      <amp-video
        layout="fixed"
        autoplay
        loop
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        poster="https://i.imgur.com/lNFDJb1.png"
      >
        <source src="https://i.imgur.com/3TFahoU.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <div fallback>
          <p>This browser does not support this video element.</p>
        </div>
      </amp-video>
    </amp-carousel>

    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="Centered">
        Providing solutions for all your surface treatments
      </h1>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <div>
          <p class="left">
            Reliant Industrial Supply provides solutions for all your surface
            treatments.Our supplier sia Coated Abrasives, the oldest abrasive
            manufacturer in the world, brings one of the best abrasives on the
            market. We supply Flex Trim brushes for all liner and carousel
            sanding needs. We provide AirVantage Sanders and Coilhose
            Pneumatics, for when you want the best quality handsanding tools and
            results. When it comes to machines, we have one of the best and also
            one of the most experienced machinery manufacturers, Timesavers Wide
            Belt Sanders. For cutting and shaping we have a wide variety of
            Exchangeable Saw Blades and Router Bits. Whether cutting, shaping or
            sanding, you can rely on Reliant. We provide solutions for surface
            preparation through complete sanding systems which include coated
            abrasives, pneumatic sanders and machinery.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <img
            class="right"
            src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/9b21f5a4-2e5f-41f0-8dad-efd23bed0d9a/d4afbws-c0d0181e-3af5-4396-8a25-03179fe90de4.png/v1/fill/w_800,h_200,q_80,strp/blitzle_banner_800x200_by_poketrainertk_d4afbws-fullview.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOiIsImlzcyI6InVybjphcHA6Iiwib2JqIjpbW3siaGVpZ2h0IjoiPD0yMDAiLCJwYXRoIjoiXC9mXC85YjIxZjVhNC0yZTVmLTQxZjAtOGRhZC1lZmQyM2JlZDBkOWFcL2Q0YWZid3MtYzBkMDE4MWUtM2FmNS00Mzk2LThhMjUtMDMxNzlmZTkwZGU0LnBuZyIsIndpZHRoIjoiPD04MDAifV1dLCJhdWQiOlsidXJuOnNlcnZpY2U6aW1hZ2Uub3BlcmF0aW9ucyJdfQ.i-LS_KPDS28_jEfNNLQ7CuIXHSH38heUTJKHQU_ZYZc"
            layout="responsive"
            width="800px;"
            height="200px;"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```